# Increase Internal Buffer Size Used by Java FileInputStream

Tags: java, stream, io, inputstream, fileinputstream

When calling `read(byte[])` on a `FileInputStream`, the read size is always 8k, even if `byte[]` is exponentially large.

**How do you increase the max read amount returned per call?**

Please do not suggest a method that merely masks the limitation of `FileInputStream`.

---

**Update:** There doesn't seem to be a real solution to this. However, I calculated the method call overhead to about 226uS on my system, for 1G file. It's probably safe to say this is not going to impact the performance in any real way.

Comment: Does that include manually using a [BufferedInputStream](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a BufferedInputStream which allows you to specify the buffer size.

Comment: Doesn't this just wrap the fileinputstream read method in a while loop?

Comment: Will it help the fact that the underlying FileInputStream will issue an OS read() every 8k? Well, maybe OS's I/O subsystem will batch several consecutive reads together, but the overhead of Java-to-OS call is still here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to memory map the file by using NIO, but I'm not sure what the problem with 8K is.
You can either copy the 8K to your bigger array or use the returned length to call

```
public int read(byte[] b,
                int off,
                int len)
         throws IOException
```

With off being the return value from the last read.

Comment: Reading a 1G file at 8K is 2^17 method calls. I'm interested in benchmarking with lower JVM overhead.

Comment: In that case FileChannel.map might work better for you, although I don't see a problem with those calls. The JVM will optimize away most of the overhead anyways.

Comment: Also the OS/FS are responsible for their own read-ahead buffers. So once it gets in-step the system calls should be relatively cheap. (E.g. what is overhead of system call for the IO read itself?)

Comment: What makes you believe the JVM will optimize it away? If that were the case, it should perform a read larger than 8k when possible.

Comment: The overhead is ~226uS ... not much

Comment: I'm glad you found this to be a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

The size of each read you see might be the buffer size used by the operating system itself. So you might have to make a change at the OS level. How you do that would be system dependent. You might be able to specify the block size when creating the file system. This has traditionally been possible for Unix filesystems. Although ironically I believe the feature was used to have smaller blocks for filesystems expected to have many small files.